Continuity of the complex logarithm
I am trying to show that the complex logarithm $\operatorname{Log}:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
($D=\mathbb{C}\setminus \{\operatorname{Re}(z)\leq 0, \operatorname{Im}(z)=0\}$) is continuous:
$\operatorname{Log}(z)=\log|z|+i\operatorname{Arg}(z)$, where $\operatorname{Arg}(z)\in(-\pi,\pi]$ is the main argument of the complex number $z$. Since the real logarithm is continuous, $\operatorname{Log}$ is continuous $\iff$ $\operatorname{Arg}$ is continuous.
However, I have no idea how to prove rigorously that $\operatorname{Arg}$ is continuous.
Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks for any help!

Or use the integral representation $\int_1^z t^{-1}\mathrm dt$ instead.

Using polar coordinates one obtains well known continuous formulas for $\text{Arg}(z)$ in each of the three relevant open half-planes:
$$\text{Arg}(z) = \begin{cases}
\tan^{-1} \left(\frac{\text{Im}(z)}{\text{Re}(z)}\right) & \quad\text{if $\text{Re}(z) > 0$} \\
\cot^{-1} \left(\frac{\text{Re}(z)}{\text{Im}(z)}\right) & \quad\text{if $\text{Im}(z) > 0$} \\
\cot^{-1} \left(\frac{\text{Re}(z)}{\text{Im}(z)}\right) - \pi & \quad\text{if $\text{Im}(z) < 0$}
\end{cases}
$$

And this is continuous because $Im$ and $Re$ are continuous complex functions?

Yes, $\text{Re}(x+iy)=x$ and $\text{Im}(x+iy)=y$ are continuous functions. Continuity for this is a lot easier to prove for those than for inverse tangent, for cotangent, and for division, in fact.
